# Link multiple choice list column to the document/s to be uploaded in the document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, custom-list, modern-experience, links

So I have items in the list which is linked to the documents in the document library using lookup columns where users can see how many documents have been linked to the selected list item.

The scenario is below.

User changes the status of the choice column from **"todo"** into **"completed"** in the list and they want it **to be tagged or somewhat linked** **to the document or documents to be uploaded** once they have completed in the list for that column. I couldn't find any information or tips to implement the scenario I have mentioned above.
I was thinking of creating lookup columns to link choice columns from the list but unfortunately, lookup columns do not support choice columns. 
Also, I have already implemented validation rules to the choice columns so because of the nature of the project **I can not use a lookup column instead of a choice column.**

I would appreciate any suggestions or alternatives to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s my suggestion:

1. Create a choice column in the document library same as the choice field in the list.
2. Create a Flow in the list to update the choice filed based on the list item.
   [image]
3. Here’s an additional step. 
   If you want to promote list item properties to the document content as contents or tags, please do as following:

   a. Edit the template for the document library via Library Settings > Advanced settings > Document Template > Edit Template (if you don’t have multiple content types in this library).

   b. Open the template and then insert the column via Insert > Quick Parts > Document Property. The Choice field value will be updated in the document property.

   [image]

Comment: Using flow will only update the columns to the already uploaded file/s into the document library but not the file or files to be uploaded to the document library after the process. The objective is uploading file/s to the choice column together with its multiple-choice value which is out of the box problem I believe. I can create exactly the same columns in the document library too but this way user has to do the process twice. I forgot to mention for the files to be uploaded so I will mark it useful and wait for alternative suggestions if you have. Again thanks for your effort on this.

Comment: The problem here is, the user creates the list item first and then uploads the document into the document library which is attached to the link item using the lookup column. However, I can not create lookup columns for the multiple-choice columns as an alternative which makes it complex so I'm not sure what kind of alternative I can implement. Something like user chooses the column and set it completed then a popup screen appears. The user (uploades file/s or does not) into that completed section which uploades the file into the document library with a link attached to the column value.

Comment: @Abbas If the newly uploaded document is not linked to the list item, does it still need to be tagged?
'Cause the flow runs every time you modify an item in the list, including when you add the new added/uploaded document to the list via the lookup column.  Multiple choice fields can be updated for sure. But I don’t think I have understood your situation right. It sounds like a lot of work to do.